# mysqlsh storing passwords broken?

Tags: mysql

MySQL Shell 8.0.12
On Mac

I go through this every time I login:

```
 ❯ mysqlsh --mysql -u me -h server.blah.com                                                                                                                                                                                         [15:53:36]
Creating a Classic session to 'me@server.blah.com'
Please provide the password for 'me@server.blah.com': 
Save password for 'me@server.blah.com:3306'? [Y]es/[N]o/Ne[v]er (default No): Y
```

Never seems to save my password. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: This is probably a bug. Try as workaround add port parameter `-P3306`, i.e. `mysqlsh --mysql -u me -h server.blah.com -P3306`.

Comment: damn that totally works, adding the port param doesnt prompt for password again! Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bug. Try as workaround add port parameter `-P3306`, i.e. `mysqlsh --mysql -u me -h server.blah.com -P3306`